# Averaging the inner lists of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have the following dictionary:

```
dict_ = {0: {40: [0.692, 0.76, 0.01]}, 1: {33: [0.69, 0.02]}, 2: {39: [0.698, 0.023]}}
```

I want to average the inner lists together so that I generate a final averaged list something like this: `[(0.692+0.690.698)/3, (0.76+0.02+0.023)/3, (0.01+0.0+0.0)/3]`. My following code is:

```
for i in dict_:
    for j in dict_[i]:
        W = [sum(e) / len(e) for e in zip(*dict_[i][j])]
print(W)
```

Has this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 97, in <module>
    W = [sum(e) / len(e) for e in zip(* dict_[i][j])]
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

How can I fix that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dict_ = {0: {40: [0.692, 0.76, 0.01]}, 1: {33: [0.69, 0.02]}, 2: {39: [0.698, 0.023]}}
inner_sum = [[sum(c)/float(len(c)) for d, c in b.items()][0] for a, b in dict_.items()]
```

**Edit**: it appears that you are trying to zip the inner lists and if the lengths of each list are not the same, replace the expected value with 0:

```
import itertools
final_data = [[0 if b is None else b for b in i] for i in itertools.izip_longest(*[b.values() for a, b in dict_.items()])][0]
print(final_data)
averages = [sum(i)/float(len(i)) for i in final_data]
print(averages)
```

Output:

```
[[0.692, 0.69, 0.698], [0.76, 0.02, 0.023], [0.01, 0, 0]]
[0.6933333333333334, 0.26766666666666666, 0.0033333333333333335]
```

For Python3, use `zip_longest` instead:

```
final_data = [[0 if b is None else b for b in i] for i in itertools.zip_longest(*[b.values() for a, b in dict_.items()])]
```

Comment: Oh! This is great and simple! Thank you very much. Waiting 10 min to accept this answer. THANK YOU

Comment: Also, instead of using `for a, b in dict_.items()` you could just use `for b in dict_.values()`

Comment: @David glad to help!

Comment: @Ajax1234 Can you tell me why I am getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 108, in <module>
    averages = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in final_data]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: @David apologies, fixed now. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

I had some fun and converted it into a oneliner.

Please **don't** use it in production code!

```
d = {0: {40: [0.692, 0.76, 0.01]}, 1: {33: [0.69, 0.02]}, 2: {39: [0.698, 0.023]}}

print(map(lambda L: sum(L)/len(L),map(lambda L:map(lambda v:float(v or 0),L),map(None,*[L for nd in d.values() for L in nd.values()]))))
```

where:

```
d: your dict
nd: nested dict in d
L: a list
v: an element (in the list L)
```